# How to train TextBlob MaxEntClassifier more quickly?

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, sentiment-analysis, textblob

I'm using Textblob MaxEntClassifier for sentiment analysis, just the positive and negative classes. On a fairly small training set, 3,800 short Tweets, the training takes way too long, approximately an hour and 15 mins. TextBlob goes  through "Training (100 iterations)" even when the Log Likelihood and Accuracy stopped changing after the 32 iteration. (On a side note, I have 12gb of RAM and 3.4ghz processor with not much else running in the background).

I see that the Textblob MaxEntClassifier is a wrapper around the NLTK. I found in the [Textblob docs](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/api_reference.html#textblob.classifiers.NLTKClassifier.train) that mentioned "train(*args, **kwargs) - Train the classifier with a labeled feature set and return the classifier. Takes the same arguments as the wrapped NLTK class..."

Since the TextBlob MaxEntClassifier train takes the same args as the wrapped NLTK class, I reviewed the NLTK docs for a param that might shorten the training time. In the [NLTK.classify docs](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.classify.html) under the MaxEnt Classifier I found the param "min_lldelta=v: Terminate if a single iteration improves log likelihood by less than v.". I was hopeful that I could pass this param through TextBlob to the NLTK classifier to shorten the training time, however it seems to be ignored.

Is it possible to pass max_iter, min_ll, or min_lldelta through Textblob MaxEntClassifier to the NLTK to shorten the training time? If not, are there other ways to shorten this training time?

My snippet is below:

```
# Most code below from: https://stevenloria.com/simple-text-classification/

from textblob.classifiers import MaxEntClassifier

train = [
    ('I love this sandwich.', 'pos'),
    ('This is an amazing place!', 'pos'),
    ('I feel very good about these beers.', 'pos'),
    ('This is my best work.', 'pos'),
    ("What an awesome view", 'pos'),
    ('I do not like this restaurant', 'neg'),
    ('I am tired of this stuff.', 'neg'),
    ("I can't deal with this", 'neg'),
    ('He is my sworn enemy!', 'neg'),
    ('My boss is horrible.', 'neg')
]
test = [
    ('The beer was good.', 'pos'),
    ('I do not enjoy my job', 'neg'),
    ("I ain't feeling dandy today.", 'neg'),
    ("I feel amazing!", 'pos'),
    ('Gary is a friend of mine.', 'pos'),
    ("I can't believe I'm doing this.", 'neg')
]

print("\nTraining...")
classifier = MaxEntClassifier(train, min_lldelta = 0.5)
print("\nkwargs: ", classifier.format_kwargs)

print("\nTesting...")
results = classifier.accuracy(test)
```